# Delete consecutive duplicate lines using unix utilities

Tags: bash, unix, duplicates, utility

This sounds simple on its face but is actually somewhat more complex. I would like to use a unix utility to delete consecutive duplicates, leaving the original. But, I would also like to preserve other duplicates that do not occur immediately after the original. For example, if we have the lines:

```
O B 
O B 
C D 
T V
O B
```

I want the output to be:

```
O B 
C D
T V
O B
```

Although the first and last lines are the same, they are not consecutive and therefore I want to keep them as unique entries.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do:

```
cat file1 | uniq > file2
```

or more succinctly:

```
uniq file1 file2
```

assuming `file1` contains

```
O B
O B
C D
T V
O B
```

For more details, see [man uniq](https://linux.die.net/man/1/uniq). In particular, note that the `uniq` command accepts two arguments with the following syntax: `uniq [OPTION]... [INPUT [OUTPUT]]`.

Finally if you'd want to remove all duplicates (and sort the file along the way), you could do:

```
sort -u file1 > file2
```